# Android unit testing: connectedAndroidTest does not execute my test case

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit

I am trying to add some unit tests to my app. I am developing my app in Android Studio

This is what I did.

- Added a new package
- Created a class in new package which extends `TestCase`
- Added following method to created class

`@SmallTest
public void basicTest() {
    assertEquals("abc", "abc");
}`

- Added following to `defaultConfig` section in `build.gradle`

`testApplicationId "newly.added.package.name"
testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"`

- Executed following command in Android Studio Terminal

`gradlew.bat connectedAndroidTest`

But, when I checked the generated html report, it shows that 0 tests were run.

I tried following, but none of them made a difference to the output of `gradlew.bat connectedAndroidTest` command.

- Added an incorrect package name to `testApplicationId` in `build.gradle`.
- Disconnected device

Why doesn't my test case get executed? What have I missed?

Following is my `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.package.name"
        minSdkVersion 12
        targetSdkVersion 18
        testApplicationId "my.package.name.tests"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':my_sub_module1')
    compile project(':my_sub_module2')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.2'
    compile files('libs/my_dependent_lib-1-7-4.jar')
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: Post `build.gradle`. In order to run `connectedAndroidTest` your test must located in `androidTest`.

Comment: Added `build.gradle`

Comment: If you have not written any "tests" yet. You should consider using the new `android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner`, please see here: https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/EspressoSetupInstructions. You are testing the views?

Comment: I haven't written any proper tests yet. The test I am going to do now is not related to views but I need to test views later. I replaced `android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner` with `android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner` but still no luck.

Comment: If you are testing "clicking on the views", then you need the runner. You can't just swap them out, you need to follow the link.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following testInstrumentationRunner:

```
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

Also, click **Build Variants** on the left side of Android Studio, and select

> Android Instrumentation Tests

in the dropdown.